# cassandra 2.1 -> 3.0 upgrade restrictions

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I'm trying to understand restrictions of upgrade from/to different versions of cassandra.

On the one hand, Cassandra docs
http://docs.datastax.com/en/upgrade/doc/upgrade/cassandra/upgradeC_c.html

are saying "Cassandra 3.0.x restrictions: Upgrade from Cassandra 2.1 versions greater or equal to 2.1.9...", and I understand that as 'you couldn't upgrade to 3.0 from 2.1.8 and prior 2.1.* versions'.

On the other hand, there are no any restrictions on upgrading from, say, 2.1.8 (version prior to 2.1.9) to 2.1.11 (version grater then 2.1.9), in particular, 2.1.8->2.1.11 upgrade don't require upgrade of sstables.

So, could someone explain, why it's possible to upgrade from 2.1.9 to 3.0 but not from 2.1.8 to 3.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docs restrict you from upgrading from early 2.1 versions to 3.0 because there are bug fixes and stability improvements in the later 2.1 releases that affect upgrades.

The best practice is to go to the latest patch on your branch before upgrading a major release. I.E. go to the latest 2.1.x and then go to 3.0.

Note: 3.0.0 dropped last night and it is very early in its release cycle. Make sure you test thoroughly in a qa environment before upgrading your production instance and follow the upgrade docs carefully.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not going to upgrade to 3.0 right now, but trying to figure out what i should do to be ready to upgrade from my current version (2.1.8) to 3.x when it will be ready for production usage.

Comment: But, i still don't understand the difference between starting 3.0 with data in sstables previously produced by 2.1.8, and starting 3.0 with sstables previously produced by 2.1.9 and greater, since sstables' format is the same?

Comment: Streaming etc needs to happen. You want a stable release when you upgrade.

Comment: You don't need to upgrade sstables from 2.1.8 to 2.1.9 or greater. You do need to upgrade sstables from 2.1.x to 3.0.x. Long story short, there is more to the upgrade internally than just sstables.